# .Net Framework in Wine in CentOS 5.5

Tags: .net, centos, wine

Is it possible to install and run .Net Framework under wine in CentOS 5.5 and then compile and execute .Net applications developed in windows under wine easily using the framework installed.

i have read across the Internet that we can install .Net Framework under wine in linux, but i am unable to install or execute the .Net apps under wine in linux.

if we can install .Net under wine in linux, then which frameworks (2.0SP2, 3.5SP1, 4.0) can be installed under wine in linux (CentOS 5.5), and how to install the frameworks and then execute .Net apps.

Kindly please help me in this.

Thanks

Looking for favorable answers.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)? It comes with the .Net framework and you dont need to install Wine at all.

Comment: It doesn't _come with_ the .Net framework; it _is_ (an alternate) .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), and for the hollow check in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes dear you can install .net Frameworks (Mono Version or Dot GNU version) on any linux based Operating System , as Cent is Linux Distribution so you can easily install MONO from 
[Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), which will solve your purpose, it's one of the best open source .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

.Net 4 isn't available and 3.5 is not quite there yet. I can run .net executable and have been doing so for the past week.

Mono is a good option to explore but be warned, if you plan to use WPF you might be better with Wine as it's not supported (and is not planned to be supported). I'm in the process of working up to trying WPF in Wine with forced software rendering - I've been told it may be possible.

You should also try winetricks http://www.winetricks.org if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

also confused about the installation, as quoted 'Mono is not quite a 100% fully functional alternative to .NET, so you could just be running up against a missing function of some kind. Wine is probably just spitting out a default error message for .NET related errors. You could try installing actual .NET in Wine, but depending on the version, you might not have any better luck: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManage...ation&iId=2586'